# Chrome + RTL - input causes chrome to freeze when deleting part of the text and clicking outside

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, freeze, right-to-left

When using Google Chrome and using either attribute dir="rtl" or style direction:rtl,
type text into input, and mark some it **including the beginning of the text** and delete it.

After that, click outside the input and the window is frozen.

Example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlmogTayeb/k7f6jd4t/)

```
    <div dir="rtl">
        <input class="input" />
    </div>
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?
I haven't been able to find any references for this issue.

I have tried this with Google Chrome version 110.0.5481.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Also: This doesn't happen on Firefox.